# Android studio canary doesn't preview jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, preview, android-jetpack-compose

so after jetpack compose beta was released, I updated my Android Studio Canary to the latest version, but I can't preview my app, even when I annotate my code with @Preview, there is no button called show preview or show code, they just disappeared.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 1 day I realized that I had to download Android Studio Canary from the website, and all thing worked just fine with the new compose beta.
Download the '**Android studio Arctic Fox**' from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?gclid=Cj0KCQiA4feBBhC9ARIsABp_nbX20IMQMZ3jGahF6-ki9aAja7U8jc8ZEwUUZ8lip3aQLoJ93ZMLEZQaAjUXEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 3):

Your UI code needs to be inside a compose fuction.

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text (text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

The composable function must not take any parameters. For this reason, you can't preview the Greeting() function directly. Instead, make a second function named PreviewGreeting(), which calls Greeting() with an appropriate parameter. Add the @Preview annotation before @Composable.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewGreeting() {
    Greeting("Android")
}
```

Comment: I created another project (it uses 1.0.0-alpha04 by default) and it works, but when I change the version to the new beta, it does not

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

My code was

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun FooPreview() {
    Foo()
}
```

Surrounding the Method-Code with

```
MyAppTheme{
    ....
}
```

like this

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun FooPreview() {
    MyAppTheme{
        Foo()
    }
}
```

fixed it